# How does the semicolon work at the beginning of "for"?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, syntax

I just came across this code on the Mozilla site and, while to me it looks broken, it's likely I am not familiar with its use:

```
for (; k < len; k++)
    {
      if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement)
        return k;
    }
```

How does the semicolon work at the beginning of the loop?

The full code is [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/IndexOf)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first part is the *initial-expression* that is used to initialize variables (see [`for` construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)):

```
 for ([initial-expression]; [condition]; [final-expression])
    statement
```

The brackets mean in this case that it’s optional. So you don’t need to write any initializer expression if you don’t have any variables to initialize. Like in this case where `k` is initialized before the `for` loop:

```
var k = n >= 0
      ? n
      : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);

for (; k < len; k++)
{
  if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement)
    return k;
}
```

You could also write it as *initial-expression* part but that wouldn’t be that readable:

```
for (var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0); k < len; k++)
{
  if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement)
    return k;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realise the variables were optional it makes sense now seeing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

it's mean that declaration and initialization k variable is something upper;

If you want skip some **for** section, you just put semicolon, e.g.:

```
for (;;) {
  //infinite loop
}
```

Comment: true - too much english gramma :)