# Omitting Condition in For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Can someone please help me understand why the following code works:

```
var someNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var length = someNumbers.length;

for(var i=length; i--;) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

How does this for loop know to terminate once `i` equates to `0`? What about negative numbers? Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5289472/1317805.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Javascript, anything can be a condition! In this case, it's `i--`. Once `i--` returns `0` the loop will stop because `0` is falsy.

The part that's missing is the third expression (the "final expression", see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) page on the `for` loop) where you usually find the increment/decrement operation, but both are combined in the "condition" expression in this case.

Comment: +1 But the third expression could just as easily be something like `for(var i=length; i--;console.log(i));` (not that it's any clearer that way).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the clarification! Right after I posted this, I noticed the subtle ';' after i-- which I was skipping over, thinking that i-- was actually the final-expression.

Answer (score 2):

This is how `for` loops work. MDN covers `for` loops in [a lot of detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), but to paraphrase:

> ### Syntax
>
> `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]) statement`
>
> #### `condition`
>
> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true. **If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.**

`0` in JavaScript is [*falsy*](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) - this means that it evaluates to `false` when evaluated as a Boolean expression.

What your `for` loop essentially does is assign the value stored in your `length` variable to your `i` variable, then subtracts 1 from it every time the loop iterates. Eventually, your `i` variable will be equal to 0. Here it will stop looping and move on to the next statement after the `for` loop.

This would create an infinite loop if your `length` variable was negative, but that shouldn't happen with the code you've provided.

Comment: Negative numbers are not falsy.

Answer (score 0):

The decrement method mentioned is for

```
 for(var i=length; i--;) {
    console.log(i);
     }
```

Is there a performance difference between `for (var i=length; i--;)` &

```
 for (var i=length; i>0; i--)
    {
    console.log(i);
    }
```

Those are not equivalent. The first loop goes through `length-1 to 0` inclusively while the second one goes `length to 1`. 
The first loop is easy to be turn in infinite loop. If the value of the length is less than 0 the loop is infinite. It is definitely better to use the second form. Even it is longer it is safer and more readable version.